# Files disappear from a flash drive

Tags: usb-drive, format

When I put some files on my flash drive from my Linux machine and put the drive to the windows machine they disappear. The same happens when I do the opposite - when I put some files to the drive from my windows machine and put it to linux machine. How to properly format the USB flash drive?

I did the following:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
$ sudo umount /dev/sdb*
$ sudo wipefs --all /dev/sdb
$ sudo cfdisk /dev/sdb
$ sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdb1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `sudo fdisk -l` to see the list of attached device and note down your target device
2. `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX` to wipe it to null (change X with a/b/c etc. as per the device name from the 1st command)
3. `sudo fdisk /dev/sdX`and then type m for help
4. `n` to create a new partition
5. Then `p` for Primary partion
6. Then `w` to write changes
7. `sudo fdisk -l` again to see the new partition name, it should now have 1/2/3 etc. after sdX
8. `sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdXx` where X=a//b/c etc. and x=1/2/3 etc. (better use `sudo mkfs.fat -F 32 /dev/sdXx` for full support always and on every OS)

Done

Comment: Thanks! seems like this helped!

Answer (score 0):

From linux do. This will zero the partation

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
```

Then install gparted

```
sudo apt install gparted -y
```

run gparted. From right top corner select your drive. And from menu bar select `Device>Create partation table` to create new partation table as GPT. Lear about [creating partation table](https://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dhelp-manual#gparted-create-partition-table)

Now right click the unallocated space and create a new primary partation as FAT32(this is standard world-wide supported but you can select any)

Comment: when do I run the first command? after I wipe everything? 

how to run gparted? sorry, but I am new to linux. Also, I would like to use NTFS, since FAT32 allows a file up to 4 GB only

Comment: run first command in terminal as it is but replace /dev/sdb with your device  and it is also ok to use ntfs

Comment: is gparted necessary? can I go with `sudo mkfs.ntfs /dev/sdb1 ` instead?

Comment: It makes things easy so better to go simply.

Comment: dont forget to create new partation table

Comment: how to create new partition table?

Comment: https://gparted.org/display-doc.php%3Fname%3Dhelp-manual#gparted-create-partition-table